# SQL Server database project & .NET Framework 3.5 can't use TimeZoneInfo class

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015

Built and deployed successfully to a SQL Server 2012 database using .NET framework 4.5

Tried to deploy to SQL Server 2008 database and realised .NET Framework 3.5 is required. Went into Dev machine (Win 7) Windows features and fully activated 3.5

A test Windows application project can declare a `TimeZoneInfo` class object  when its .NET framework property is 3.5

The SQL Server Database Project can't, all instances of `TimeZoneInfo` in the code are now red lined.

So it seems the .NET Framework 3.5 has a restricted 'access' from a SQL Server Database Project

I have double checked that the target platform is SQL Server 2008.

Tried setting the SQLCLR Permission level to Unsafe. No difference.

Created a new dummy empty SQL Server Database Project, it behaves the same. Happy at 4.5 sad at 3.5.

I don't have earlier IDEs on this machine so can't say whether it is a VS2015 peculiarity or not.

FURTHER INFO which may help others;
After pursuing Alexei's lead about references thereby getting a compilable project, I found the following  on S.O. leading to a successful deployment on SqlServer 2008 database.

1) Leave the project permission level set to Safe. (You will make the assembly unsafe using SSMS later)

2) Using SSMS with sufficient privileges execute

- EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa' ALTER DATABASE MyDatabaseName SET TRUSTWORTHY
  ON
- Alter Database [MyDatabaseName] set Trustworthy ON

3) Deploy the project

4) Using SSMS Execute

- ALTER ASSEMBLY [MyAssemblyName]    WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;

The UDFs are now available.

Comment: Did you check documentation to see if all requirements are met (like referenced assembly) ? If you don't have access to search - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thx Alexei. Project needs reference to mscorlib 2 and system.core.3.5 . When it is using Framework 3.5 and TimeZoneInfo. If you put this up as answer I will tick it. regards Bob

Comment: I don't mind when see something doesn't work with .NET 3.5 and/or SQL Server 2008. Why? Stop using 10 years old software, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly the `TimeZoneInfo` class has unsafe code in it so you have to do this to make it work with SQL Server 2008:

> Because you are calling a method that has a HostProtectionAttribute (a few of the methods in TimeZoneInfo do), your assembly (the one that calls this method) must be cataloged as Unsafe also.

So my assumption is you need to turn ON the `Project > Properties > Build > Allow Unsafe Code` checkbox.

Please see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0515862-eb87-4a13-bab4-0e343983823a/problem-in-calling-timezoneinfo-from-sql-server-2005-clr?forum=sqlnetfx) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c1b44768-5608-4e58-ba83-402a5e6eb4c9/what-are-the-repercussions-of-accessing-net-timezoneinfo-object-from-sql-clr-sql2008-function?forum=sqlnetfx) forum for more info.

Comment: Be sure to add `System.Core` to the project `References`, and add `using System;` to the project.